# jquery ui datepicker. How can I show ALL of the possible years (for the birthdate)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jquery ui datepicker with changeYear.
The problem is that it shows the years in chunks (from 1985 to 2005, then clicking on 1985 opens other years) I need to show ALL the years in the range I'm passing like this:

```
$(".datepickerBDAY_trigger").datepicker({
    "dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "-16Y",
    minDate: "-100Y"
});
```

How can I do this? I cannot find this information anywhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [yearRange](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange) option. Its first form (`-nn:+nn`) allows you to specify a range relative to the current year instead of the currently selected year.

```
$(".datepickerBDAY_trigger").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "-16Y",
    minDate: "-100Y",
    yearRange: "-100:-16"
});
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUnm3/).